# Why are there no Contents-arch.gz file for Debian jessie?

Tags: debian, mirroring, debian-jessie

The mirrors

- ftp://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian/dists/
- http://ftp.gr.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/
- and many others

don't contain the file `debian/dists/jessie/Contents-amd64.gz` whereas they do for all previous releases (`wheezy`, `squeeze`). Some programs, e.g. `auto-apt` rely on them and fail to run.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the project maintainers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Contents-.gz` file location has been changed in jessie/8.x (see [this issue report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=637442) for details an a link to an explanation).